# How to extract month number in ofbiz entity

Tags: ofbiz

I have a view entity. And I have a column which shipmentDate. From this column I want to create a new column `shipmentMonthNo` by extracting the `shipmentDate`. There is an entity function named  extract-month. I used it but not working.

Experts, please help.

```
    <view-entity entity-name="MerShipmentSchedule" package-name="org.ofbiz.party.party" title="Party Relationship And Details">
    <member-entity entity-alias="MOB" entity-name="MerOrderBook"/>
    <member-entity entity-alias="PER" entity-name="Pers"/>
    <member-entity entity-alias="PTYGRP" entity-name="PartyGrp"/>
    <alias-all entity-alias="MOB"/>
    <alias name="shipmentMonthNo" entity-alias="MOB"  field="shipmentDate" function="extract-month" ></alias>
    <alias entity-alias="PER" name="nickname"/>
    <alias entity-alias="PTYGRP" name="groupName"/>
    <view-link entity-alias="MOB" rel-entity-alias="PER" rel-optional="true">
        <key-map field-name="merchandiserId" rel-field-name="partyId"/>
    </view-link>
    <view-link entity-alias="MOB" rel-entity-alias="PTYGRP" rel-optional="true">
        <key-map field-name="buyerId" rel-field-name="partyId"/>
    </view-link>
</view-entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept : 
The "extract-month" is the version of "EXTRACT" that most of the databases used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc. In this case its month, so internally it gets parsed to EXTRACT function according to the database type.

Reason : It would not be working may be because of the database settings, For example in mySql "lower_case_table_names" decided whether your database follows lowercase of uppercase.

Solution : You should check the database settings first and then specification.